# differential ADC with a potentiometer in the positive input and grounded negative input

Tags: adc, differential, texas-instruments

i have a problem in reading values from ads1672([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1672.pdf)). i setup this circuit:
[image: ads1672 with a potentiometer in the positive input and grounded negative input]

the Reference voltage is +3.V (REF5030-[TI page](http://www.ti.com/product/REF5030))

when potentiometer is @ +1.6V (i measured this by multi-meter) this out +2.9V!!
and when potentiometer is @ +1.4 the ads1672 output is -2.9V!!
 and when potentiometer is beyond +3v ads1672 output is almost +0V also when potentiometer is zero ads1672 ouput is -0V!!

Why!! any body have any idea?

**Firsts Question:** are this setup (with a potentiometer in the positive input and grounded negative input)  is good for test and setting up a **differential** **ADC**??

**Second Question:** what is **VCM** role in my circuit? (with respect to Refrence Voltage=3.v)

i think (ReferenceVoltage/2 =1.5) is center of input ads1672. is it right. but why??

Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data sheet on page 3 tells you this: -

```
Common-mode input voltage VCM = (AINP + AINN)/2 = 2.5 V typically
```

So if AINN is 0 volts then the only typically valid value for AINP is 5 volts.

You have a pot on AINP and with 0 volts on AINN this set-up won't work.

See also the notes on page 14 about how to drive the inputs - inputs need to be driven differentially and centred about 2.5 volts. See page 26 for circuit examples of interfacing to the analogue inputs of this chip.

Comment: thank for your reply... but we are not in common mode, we are in differential mode

Comment: @ali you need to read up on this and recognise that you are breaking the common mode rules for this ADC despite your attempts to apply a differential signal.